# Why is the table data being added to the heading and the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, indexeddb

I have been working on a todo list web applicaton for an assignment and have been using this code up until now:

```
const db = new Database();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      db.getAllTodos(function(records) {
          records.forEach(function() {
            console.log(records.length);
            var cols = ['taskName','taskDesc', 'taskDate','taskTime','taskPriority','taskLocation','taskImage'];
              for (var i = 0; i <= records.length; i++){
                $('table').append('<tr></tr>' );
                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                  var lastCell = $('table tr:last-child');
                  lastCell.append ('<td>' + records[i][cols[j]] + '</td>' );
                }
                  lastCell.append("<td class=\"delete\"><button  onclick=\"deleteTask()\">Delete</button><button onclick=\"editTask()\">Edit</button></td>");
              }
            })
      });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Up until now  this has worked fine but now that I am trying to use DataTables to add the ability to sort the data, the data is getting added to the heading as well as the body of the table and I can't figure out why. If I remove the code being used to initialise the DataTable the issue is persisting.

[Image showing  the table with datatable being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1krbF.png)

[Image showing the table without datatable being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9moE.png)

Since yesterday I've been working on this and looking at the chrome debugging tools but I'm getting nowhere, the code is exactly the same as before, I even copy pasted it from a previous save I have and the same issue persists. I thought instead that it might be to do with using a JQuery import link from the DataTables website so I tested again with standard JQuery and it was exactly the same. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It worked until you added DataTables but when you removed DataTables it doesn't work? We need a more specific question I think, more than it doesn't work. Any specific errors?

Comment: No errors other than a pre-existing one from way before which didn't seem to cause any issues. pretty much before I tried to use the datatable, it worked perfectly, but now that I am using it it now appends all the data twice. I removed the piece of code which initialises the datatable and it continues to be broken, so I am not sure what is going on with it. The 2 screenshots I linked show what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the  tags. I am not sure why, but removing them has solved the issue of the data appending. In the end I also decided not to use datatables at all as its compatibility with the code I have already written is not great.